# DataPoint save date exponential

Tags: java, android-studio, datapoint

I have a problem, i make an app witch show a graph based on data from firebase.
But when i saved on DataPoint its change my first value witch is date and time to an exponential.

This is the main function witch take data from firebase and save to a DataPoint

[image: DataPoint]

This is PointValue function used to get data. The value ar going good heare

[image: PointValue function]

This is DataPoint function. And heare value is exponential.

[image: DataPoint.java]

Answer (score 0):

I fiind how to resolve the problem. I save date and time in miliseconds.  [I used this cod for retrive data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcwhZztfY2g)

When i debugg the original code i noticed java fucntion data().getTime() return miliseconds.